# Modify reg exp to set 4 digits or blank as valid

Tags: regex

I need to use a reg exp and 4 digits or none shall be valid.

My regexp looks like this now:

```
([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]
```

But i need to modify it so it also accepts blank.

Would the reg exp look something like this then?

```
([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]?[]
```

Comment: The regexp is to validate a field and the field would be valid if it contains 4 digits or is blank.

Comment: is blank valid or not?

Comment: Yes a blank line is valid as i said in last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the four digits as optional.

```
^(?:([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9])?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gS3iY5/4)

See it matches a blank link in the above demo link.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
^([0-9]{4})?(\[])?$
```

**Demo:**
http://regex101.com/r/zD6iJ3/3